# issues with iframe in phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe

I have an IOS App which needs to load some external url in an iframe inside the app.

My code looks like

```
<body>

    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.google.co.in/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div class="footer"></div>

</body>
```

cordova plist:

```
OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView: YES
ExternalHosts: *
```

but I am getting an error whenever I tried to load the page

"Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)"

I am not able to load the external url

Could anyone help me out to solve this

Comment: This works fine for me in PhoneGap-2.3.0. Tested in iPhone

Comment: Google doesn't allow x-frame meaning you can't load google into an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

update your config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: Thanks Dato', that got my site to show up, but it isn't showing up as a mobile site for some reason.  Seems to think it's a full desktop version even though is built responsively.  Investigating this next...